# How to connect raspberry pi to an open WiFi network (like in shopping mall)?

Tags: wifi, pi-3, wireless, archlinux, kali

I am using Kali image (2.1.2). I tried to connect to open WiFi network editing the file `/etc/network/intefaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp    
wpa-ssid "openWiFi"
wpa-psk  ""
```

It doesn't work. I also tried replacing `wpa-psk  ""` with `wpa-psk`. *MAC address of RPi is whitelisted*.
How to connect to open WiFi, provided only SSID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Replace `wpa-ssid "openWiFi"` with `wireless-essid openWiFi` (no double quotes around the network ssid) and remove `wpa-psk`. `/etc/network/intefaces` should look like

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp  
wireless-essid openWiFi #Replace "openWiFi" with the network name you want to connect
```

Answer (score -1):

do you mean `web-base` access for `authentication` ?

lot of these public wifi spots use weird hacky ways to get that portal screen to pop up and I find that Linux often does not automatically get an IP address.

so please check `dhclient` :

`sudo dhclient`

it will refresh the automatic ip.

Comment: No web based authentication. MAC address of the raspberry pi is whitelisted.

Comment: can you try `sudo dhclient` ? or you want to configure network interface ?

Comment: or just install a network-manager in terminal